# UISearchBar in a NavigationBar width

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would like to have an `UISearchbar` in my NavigationBar - as I've done here:

[image]
When the SearchBar gets the Focus, I'll remove the left Button with:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = []
```

And try to make the `UISearchBar` getting the whole width of the Screen (with a Cancel Button)

```
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
```

But my `UISearchBar` is too wide, it looks like in this screen:

[image]

But why is that? I want to get the following result:

User clicks into the SeachBar, I'll FadeIn a `UITableView` for the Results - when the User presses the Cancel Button, the `UITableView` fades out and I'll add the "Kategorie" left Button again.

Is this a way how to solve that - or can I not use the `sizeToFit()` method here?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you placed your searched bar as a `rightBarButtonItem` and that spot has a right margin. Your searchBar is trying to expand to be the full width of the screen, hence it gets to be too wide.

I used a search controller and implemented `didPresentSearchController` and resized it there.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the width of the search bar equal to the screen minus the size of the 'Cancel' button, or try to add constraints between the search bar and leading space to the navigation controller.

Comment: I dont want that - i though that "sizeToFit()" automatically takes all the available space in the container. If possible (because its an universal app) i would like to use the basic features without calculating the "needed" space for each UI element.